# Proof of vectorization of product of three matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product, vectorization

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products), it is written that $$\mathrm{vec}(ABC) = (C^\top\otimes A)\mathrm{vec}(B)$$
I am trying to show that it is true, but couldn't succeed. $A$ is $m\times n$, $B$ is $n\times p$ and $C$ is $p\times q$ matrix.

**My attempts**

The $ij$th element of the matrix $ABC$ is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^pa_{ik}b_{kl}c_{lj}$$
Now, since $ABC$ is an $m\times q$ matrix, so if

$$i = am+b;\hspace{1cm}a\in\Bbb N,0<b<m$$
then the $i$th element of $\mathrm{vec}(ABC)$ is actually the element in the $b$th row and $a+1$th column in the matrix $ABC$ which can be found by the above double sum. But I don't know what to do for the RHS.

Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an approach I like, which avoids getting bogged down in summation and the vectorization reindexing wherein the $i,j$ entry of an $m \times n$ matrix becomes the $[1 + i + m(j-1)]$th entry of a length $mn$ column-vector.

We first observe that the maps $B \mapsto \operatorname{vec}(ABC)$ and $B \mapsto (C^T \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B)$ are linear maps from $\Bbb R^{n \times p}$ to $\Bbb R^{mq}$.  In order to show that these maps are identical, it suffices to show that they agree on a basis.

One particularly nice basis of $\Bbb R^{n \times p} = \{E_{ij}: 1 \leq i \leq n, 1 \leq j \leq p\}$, where $E_{ij}$ denotes the matrix that has a $1$ as its $(i,j)$ entry and zeros everywhere else. We make two observations:

- $E_{ij} = e_i^{(n)}{e_j^{(p)}}^T$ where $e_1^{(n)},\dots,e_n^{(n)}$ denotes the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$,
- $\operatorname{vec}(uv^T) = v \otimes u$ for any vectors $u,v$ (this in turn can be proven by first considering the case where $u,v$ are standard basis vectors), then making an argument by linearity.

We then have
$$
\begin{align*}
(C^T \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(E_{ij}) &= 
(C^T \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(e_i^{(n)}[e_j^{(p)}]^T) 
\\ &= 
(C^T \otimes A)(e_j^{(p)} \otimes e_i^{(n)}) 
\\ & = 
(C^Te_j^{(p)}) \otimes (Ae_i^{(n)}).
\end{align*}
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\operatorname{vec}(AE_{ij}C) = \operatorname{vec}(Ae_i^{(n)}[e_j^{(p)}]^TC)= 
\operatorname{vec}([Ae_i^{(n)}][C^Te_j^{(p)}]^T) = (C^Te_j^{(p)}) \otimes (Ae_i^{(n)}).
$$
The conclusion follows.

Comment: $E_{ij} = e_if_j$ where $e_i$ is standard basis vector for $\Bbb R^n$ and $f_j$ is that for $\Bbb R^p$. Similarly further arguments should change.

Comment: And it is $C^\top\otimes A$ and not $C^\top\otimes D$.

Comment: I am upvoting and accepting your answer, assuming that you will correct it.

Comment: That is quite some attitude you have for somebody asking for help.  You're welcome, by the way.